# Dsply Opcode to display a concatenated string

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to display few numbers in the format as below:

```
Num1 = 30
Num2 = 50
Num3 = 40
```

This I am trying to achieve through something like 
`Dsply 'Num1 = ' + %char(Num1);`

But obviously this is not working. Would I have to put the string I want to display into another field first and then use it in the Dsply opcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Num1 isn't a 'string' variable, it can't be used directly with DSPLY. Try something like:

```
Dsply ( 'Num1 = ' + %char( Num1 ));
```

You could do it other ways by copying the value into a character variable, but the %CHAR() function is easy and obvious code.

Comment: Apologies for mentioning the wrong statement in the code. What you wrote in your comment is exactly what ive been trying.Dsply 'Num1 = ' + %char(Num1);    But 'An operand was expected but was not found; specification is ignored.' is the message thrown. Unable to figure out what is wrong

Comment: @user3311539 I edited the code to include parentheses around the DSPLY operand. I should've tested first, but it seemed too simple. My mistake. Try the corrected DSPLY statement and note how the parentheses cause a single operand value to be generated. The space no longer confuses the compiler into thinking that a second operand might be intended. (DSPLY can take a second operand.)

Comment: Above solution works like a Gem. I did think about the brackets but Its funny how my mind tricks me into thinking how few of the things used in Java or C will not work in RPG. But as I learn more of RPG, the more I understand its not a tough legacy language where simple solutions dont work!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `DSPLY` opcode is limited to 52 characters.
Take a look at the `Qp0zLprintf` API here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/p0zlog.htm